# Проблемы при выводе результата Java

Tags: java

Всем привет, Начинаю свой путь Java программиста,
Имеется вот такая задача:

Создайте класс Tree. Добавьте в него поля: возраст, живое ли дерево и название дерева. Создайте три конструктора:

1. Конструктор, который устанавливает только возраст и название;
2. Конструктор, который устанавливает все переменные в классе;
3. Конструктор, который ничего не устанавливает, но выводит сообщение, «Пустой конструктор без параметров сработал».

Создайте три объекта на основе класса и используйте по одному конструктору на каждый.

Я это реализовал следующим образом:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Tree tree_1 = new Tree(121,"Дуб");
        Tree tree_2 = new Tree(2302,"Секвоя",true);
        Tree tree_3 = new Tree();
        System.out.println(tree_1);
        System.out.println(tree_2);
        System.out.println(tree_3);
    }
}


public class Tree
{
    private int age;
    private boolean alive;
    private String name_tree ;

    public Tree(int age, String name_tree)
    {
        this.age=age;
        this.name_tree=name_tree;
    }
    public Tree(int age, String name_tree, boolean alive)
    {
        this.age=age;
        this.name_tree=name_tree;
        this.alive=alive;
    }
    public Tree()
    {
        System.out.println("Пустой конструктор без параметров сработал");
    }

}
```

Объясните плиз что я сделал неверно и почему при выводе появляется вот такое значение:

Пустой конструктор без параметров сработал
Tree@568db2f2
Tree@378bf509
Tree@5fd0d5ae

Результаты компиляции не те что ожидал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При печати всё преобразуется к строке. У объекта, понятное дело, неизвестно что нужно преобразовывать к строке. Ведь объекты разные бывают. Поэтому выводится просто адрес в памяти. А чтобы было человекочитаемое что-то, нужно в классе переопределить метод `toString` и написать там то, что вы хотите, чтобы выводилось. Пример

```
public String toString() {
    return "Person{"
            + "fullName='" + fullName + '\''
            + ", age=" + age
            + ", retired=" + retired
            + '}';
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое